# Can Kubernetes PV configured to use max size

Tags: storage, kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

Have NFS configured as Persistent volume in Kubernetes. Is there an option to specify entire size of the volume.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 10.244.1.4
    path: "/exports"
```

1. Is it possible to set `spec.capacity.storage` to the entire size of
   NFS volume.
2. If possible, do resizing the NFS volume reflect in k8s ?

thanks

Comment: I've been able to expand the size of a PV as necessary with just `kubectl edit`

Answer (score -1):

Shan, You can specify the size of the entire share in NFS PV. afacit, there is no quota/size check enforced in NFS plugin. Resizing of PV is under development in Kube 1.7 and currently its undergoing design review. Also, you can use GlusterFS as an another option to specify the exact size of the volume and too get dynamically provisioned.